# How can i do optional function

Tags: javascript

i need to do optional function.
How can i do like this:

```
  console.log(db.(x==true ? input(...) : ["no function"]).query(...));
// if x is true console.log(db.input(...).query(...));
// if x is false console.log(db.query(...));
```

Comment: what do you mean by `db.["no function"].query(...)` in the `else` of the  `?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to compare `x` with `true`:

```
console.log((x ? db.input(...) : db).query(...));
```

You want to call `query` either on `db` or on `db.input(...)` depending on `x`.

Example:

```js
const db = { input() { return { query() { return 'db.input(...).query(...)'; } } }, query() { return 'db.query(...)'; } };

console.log((true ? db.input() : db).query());
console.log((false ? db.input() : db).query());
```

Comment: Your answer log like this:
//if x is true console.log(db)
//if x is false console.log(db.input(...).query(...))
But i need like this:
// if x is true console.log(db.input(...).query(...));
// if x is false console.log(db.query(...));

Comment: @UmutKalaycı No, my answer logs `db.input(...).query(...)` if `x` is truthy and `db.query(...)` if `x` is falsy. If you get `console.log(db)`, you have misplaced the parenthesis in your code.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, my bad. @jabaa

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(x === true? db.input(...).query(...) : db.query(...))
```